# connection failed while deploying symfony with capifony

Tags: php, symfony, ssh, capistrano, capifony

Thinking 2017 will be an easy year, I got stuck already. (Happy new year btw)

I have build a site in symfony and I want to deploy it.

For this i am using capifony, which can make the deployment process very easy.

My **deploy.rb** has a standard configuration file.

```
set :application, "set your application name here"
set :domain,      "ip"
set :user,        "userName"
set :use_sudo,     false
set :deploy_to,   "www/"
set :app_path,    "app"

ssh_options[:keys] = %w(/what/ever/.ssh/id_rsa)

set :repository,  "file://Users/ylamb/Documents/dev/db-yl"
set :deploy_via,  :copy
set :scm,         :git
# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `subversion`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, or `none`

set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain, :primary => true       # This may be the same as your `Web` server

set  :shared_files,        ["app/config/parameters.yml"]
set  :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads"]

set  :use_composer, true
set  :update_vendors, true


set  :keep_releases,  3

task :upload_parameters do
  origin_file = "app/config/parameters.yml"
  destination_file = shared_path + "/app/config/parameters.yml" # Notice the
  shared_path

  try_sudo "mkdir -p #{File.dirname(destination_file)}"
  top.upload(origin_file, destination_file)
end

after "deploy:setup", "upload_parameters"

# Be more verbose by uncommenting the following line
# logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
```

Now when I run the command `cap deploy:setup`

the next error appears `connection failed for: ip (Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout)`

I double checked the ip, and it is correct.

I created a ssh access key, and I am using the username from my ssh key for the `set :user`

So now I am asking, it is me or is it the hosting provider?

Many thanks